# Use text from CSV in Imagemagick

Tags: csv, imagemagick

I have a CSV with information relating to images such as name etc. , is there a way that I can  use the CSV file information to push to imagemagick (via PHP on windows) to add to the images?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php to get the CSV information into the script, then I'd assume you are using the PHP ImageMagick extension, so just run the commands against the given image, or read the image in from some variable from the file.  If you are not using the extension in PHP, you could try running it through the exec PHP method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php